# display: table-cell same space for all cells

Tags: html, css

i've got a problem with `display: table-cell;` and the space between the cells. I'd like to have dynamically the same width for all cells.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wsmx8t0/)

How you can see the `"Ausstattung & Skizze"` is much wider than the others. Is there a way to dynamically set the same width to all cells?

Comment: What “same width”? And you should include the relevant HTML and CSS in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table-layout:fixed;` on the parent element which holds `display:table;`

```
ul{
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This way, every cell will get the same width if you don't force their width, no matter how many cells you have in a row.

(Edit: see this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m8evqnv0/ )

Comment: it this responsive to you @MarkusGruber? the table width is static which is 700px.

Comment: i added width: 100%; than its responsive enough

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

edit: no need for `inline-block`, with `width:25%`

Comment: and `width: 25%` - isn't sufficient?

Comment: yea i thought the same, but the problem is, it has to be multilingual too. For example in italian some words are a lot wider than in german. So it wouldn't fit with width: 25%. I know i could play with the width a little bit to fit it in all languages. I'll use this if it's not possible with display: table;With display: table; it would be more clearlier and nicer, i think.. Thank you.

Comment: If you can post another fiddle I might help, not sure what is the problem exactly. any way - try using `max-width` and `min-width`, maybe it will answer your need

Comment: @MarkusGruber for the problem of the text is too wide that it sometimes break out of the box ,u can use `word-wrap` or `word-break` try both as they give different results.

Answer (score 0):

if the width of the unordered list is fixed, then:-

```
li
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

best practice:- use classes for li and then style the class.

if you want the table to be responsive, use table markups then. it will work like a charm.

fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/4wsmx8t0/3/

Comment: Fails when the available width is narrow enough, and produces ridiculous results when that width is very large.

Comment: of course. a responsive table should be implemented and a max width should be set because a 4 column table with only % responsiveness will not look nice when it comes to mobile. great point @JukkaK.Korpela